# Post Form Using Fetch and Check Status OK

Tags: forms, post, fetch, submit

How does one get the reponse code when posting form data using fetch with vanilla JS, I have this code which posts but does not check response code with response.ok

```
            <form method="post" id="form1" class="myForm" action="includes/vehicles/add-veh.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="4448" />
                <input type="hidden" name="vehid" id="vehid" value="84488" />
                <button type="submit" name="submit" ><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> Save To Your List</button>
                </form>
    
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.querySelector('.myForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    var data = this;
    fetch(data.getAttribute('action'), {
      method: data.getAttribute('method'),
      body: new FormData(data)
    })
            .then(res=>res.text())
      .then(function (data) {
        
     })
          .then((res) => {
    if (response.ok) { 
            alert('success');
        }
        };
    
    event.preventDefault();

  });
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.myForm').addEventListener('submit', 
  function (event) {
    var data = this;
    fetch(data.getAttribute('action'), {
      method: data.getAttribute('method'),
      body: new FormData(data)
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.ok) { 
        alert('success');
      } else {
        alert('error');
      }
    })
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).